# mongoDB, passenger and performance issues with phusion passenger

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongodb, mongomapper, passenger

i just stumbled across a posing on the mongodb-user list where there was a discussion about passenger and forking when using mongoDB with MongoMapper.

> I just wanted to remind that Rails developers need to tweak their
>   'environment.rb' if they use MongoDB with Passenger.
>
> By default, Passenger spawns Ruby processes with fork(). And, as fork
>   () shares file descriptors, the Rails app has to reopen the connection
>   to MongoDB in the fresh new "process".

http://groups.google.com/group/mongodb-user/browse_thread/thread/f31e2d23de38136a

anyone knows if there are still issues with mongoDB and passenger or what is the best way to serve a mongoDB-rails-application with passenger?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this "issue" is still around, but I think the fix was provided in both the thread you linked to (a link in the first message) and in a gist by John Nunemaker (http://gist.github.com/232953).

I believe the relevant bit of information is in the following block of code which you will place in an intializer:

```
if defined?(PhusionPassenger)
  PhusionPassenger.on_event(:starting_worker_process) do |forked|
    # if using older than 0.6.5 of MM then you want database instead of connection
    # MongoMapper.database.connect_to_master if forked
    MongoMapper.connection.connect_to_master if forked
  end
end
```

Comment: thanks a lot! i am actually enjoying working with mongoDB a lot. i am actually thinking of using it in production as well.