# mongo + passenger: right way to reconnect to database from within rails? how to ensure optimal mongo performance?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongodb, passenger, mongomapper

we're on rails 3.2.12, passenger + nginx (1.0.10), mongo 2.2, and mongomapper 0.12.

we were told that passenger and mongo don't work well together unless there is a configuration set to ensure speedy database connections (or reconnections).

however, one person advised us to use the code here: http://pastie.org/572282. then we found this post on stackoverflow ([mongoDB, passenger and performance issues with phusion passenger](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2099977/mongodb-passenger-and-performance-issues-with-phusion-passenger)), which is different.

which is the right way to ensure optimal mongo performance with passenger (and nginx)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The method to handle this changed between Mongomapper versions.

The correct way now is to use Mongomapper's convenience method in your initializer:

```
MongoMapper.connection.handle_passenger_forking
```

[See the source on Github for implementation details.](https://github.com/jnunemaker/mongomapper/blob/30e062c26dafe04c0a853f33e9f4e6cb4e251e8b/lib/mongo_mapper/connection.rb#L96)

Comment: MongoMapper uses the mongo gem underneath the hood. The mongo gem actually handles process forking for you as long as you're using v1.3.0 or greater. If you're running the latest mongo gem (1.9.0 just last week) you actually probably don't need to do this at all.